# Finding limits graphically

Tags: limits

[image: Calculating limits graphically]

> Determine lim f(x) as x approaches -2

Since there are two y values as x approaches -2 namely a gap at -1(from left and right) and a solid dot at -3, which of the following should be correct?

> The limit DNE or the limit exists at y=-1?

Thank you.

Comment: a) should be -2  and c) should be -1

Comment: see the scale numbering of graph. 2 units = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The limit of f(x) as x approaches -2 is -1.

The limit is a two-sided limit, i.e., whether the limit f(x) approaches -2 from the left or from the right, the value remains the same and therefore the limit is -1. We say, therefore, that the limit exists.

Note, however, that the 'solid' dot is a defined value which is applicable to problem related to: Determine f(-2) which is -3.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Florencio!! No one can help you but yourself. Keep going! :D